# Conditional Callback in Rails' model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback, conditional-statements

Just wondering if there is a way to do a conditional callback in Rails. I know you can do a conditional validation like so:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :if => (1==1)
```

I often do things like this in my callbacks:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :line_item_group

  before_create :set_invoice_id
  def set_invoice_id
    unless self.invoice_id
      self.invoice_id = self.line_item_group.invoice_id
    end
  end
end
```

It would be great to clean that up a little.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_invoice_id, unless: :invoice_id

  def set_invoice_id
    self.invoice_id = line_item_group.invoice_id
  end
end
```

Comment: You're right, it's not orthodox SQL, and I like it that way. :) I'm willing to sacrifice normality for less joins.

Answer (score 18):

Yes you can.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :normalize_card_number, :if => :paid_with_card?
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks for more on this topic.

Comment: I think the OP wants a refactor of the second snippet, but the question is not clear...

Comment: As I expected. Mostly wanted to post this here for the record.